# Oracle multiple caracterset

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

we are using Turkish characters in oracle database. When we use the Russian character "?" registers as a symbol. Does Oracle support multiple charsets? If so, can you help us to use the Turkish and Russian character set at the same time?

Oracle version: 11g

Here are the results when I run the query "select * from nls_database_parameters":
NLS_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY: AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY: $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY: AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS: .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET: TR8MSWIN1254
NLS_CALENDAR: GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT: DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN
NLS_SORT: BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT: HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT: DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT: HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT: DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY: $
NLS_COMP: BINARY

Regedit result
NLS_CHARACTERSET: TURKISH_TURKEY.TR8MSWIN1254

Comment: if you want to use multiple charactersets, then create a DB with unicode characterset AL32UTF8. See the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nlspg/index.html)

Comment: Current database is over 200GB. The system is currently in use and it is very difficult to recreate it. Can we add to the characterset  without rebuilding it?

Comment: Have a look at [Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71288_01/DUMAG/toc.htm), I think this will minimize the impact on your application

Answer (score 0):

Your database character set is [Windows-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254).  That means that you are only allowed to store valid Windows-1254 characters in `char`/`varchar2`/`clob` columns.  That excludes most Cyrillic characters.

Your database should have a `nls_nchar_characterset` setting in `nls_database_parameters`.  That would specify the national character set.  Assuming that is a Unicode character set (normally AL16UTF16) then you could store any valid Unicode character in an `nchar`/`nvarchar2`/`nclob` column.  But then you'd either have to change the data model to change the data types or to add additional columns for the Russian language data.  Alternately, you can migrate your database character set to a Unicode character set.

Comment: I forgot to add. NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: UTF8

Comment: @SefaKuru - Then you could store both Cyrillic and Turkish characters in `nchar`\`nvarchar2`\`nclob` columns.  Or you could migrate your database character set to a Unicode character set.

Comment: Hello, the database is actively used and we cannot store the data in a different column. How can I convert database character set to Unicode? Since the database is actively used over 200GB, I cannot pause for a long time.

Comment: @SefaKuru - 11g is rather old.  I believe the Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/dmu/19.1/ existed back then but I'd need to go through the 11g documentation to be sure.  You can do this with near zero downtime but that adds pretty significant complexity to the process (and, again, I'd need to spend some time with the 11g documentation to see what the options were back then).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll be waiting to hear from you.

Comment: @SefaKuru - What is it that you're waiting to hear from me?

Comment: I'm translating because I don't speak English. It translated as you will check the 11g documents when you wrote the previous one. I'm sorry if there is a mistake

Comment: @SefaKuru - Ah.  No, you'd need to take a look at all the old documentation.  I'm saying that I don't remember a lot of specifics because you're using an Oracle version that has been depricated for some time.  If you look at the old documentation and don't find the information you're looking for, feel free to create a new question about character set migration in 11g and include specifics about how much downtime you are prepared to tolerate and what sort of other constraints you have (for example, can you have a second copy of the database running at the same time before you do a cutover)?